# Import data from .js file with json object to mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, import

I have a javascript file which includes the data in the following format.

```
    index = {
  "me" : {
    "id" : "524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae",
    "firstName" : "A=",
    "lastName" : "T",
    "pictureName" : "66s2c.jpg",
    "username" : "a-t"
  },
  "spaces" : [ {
    "org" : {
      "id" : "524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae",
      "firstName" : "An",
      "lastName" : "Tuli",
      "pictureName" : "66s2c.jpg",
      "username" : "arli"
    }
  }, {
    "user" : {
      "id" : "60c4a171-172f-4f66-9014-8b4cf3e476e6",
      "firstName" : "Ban",
      "lastName" : "Idris",
      "pictureName" : "../../../../default-pic/butterfly_200.png",
      "username" : "banun-idris"
    }
  } ]
}
users["524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae"] = {
  "id" : "524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae",
  "firstName" : "A",
  "lastName" : "T",
  "pictureName" : "66s2c.jpg",
  "username" : "a",
  "libraries" : [ "lEy27AZavfSR", "l0yApAoo2l4b", "lJl22YOtacxY", "l0UhMCvrMmka", "lJMWpIoFnaK4", "lCZ9cYYjVJcv", "l8kynpyoaej7" ]
}
 libraries["lEy27AZavfSR"] = {
  "id" : "lEy27AZavfSR",
  "name" : "My Main Library",
  "description" : null,
  "numKeeps" : 0,
  "keeps" : [ ]
}

keeps["k4r5UIugqgfk"] = {
  "id" : "k4r5UIugqgfk",
  "keptAt" : 1449613295000,
  "lastActivityAt" : 1449613295000,
  "title" : "",
  "url" : "",
  "note" : null,
  "tags" : [ ],
  "libraries" : [ "lJl22YOtacxY" ],
  "summary" : "",
  "messages" : [ ]
}
```

I need to import data from this type of format into my mysql database.

I can't finalize and nail down the approach to do this

I tried to get the file content into a php file and then convert them into a array string but i get a null result.

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('trial_data.js');
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
var_dump($data);
```

The second approach I think i can take is load the data in jquery file and send it using AJAX to a php file which adds it to the database.

Which approach do you think i should take and  how to go about it.

Plus i need to figure out the ID from the first index array, so that I can get the ID from the me and org object for which i need to get the rest of the information

Comment: depends how much data there is. What's shown could be manually turned into json and easily read by your php in about 2 minutes. If there is a lot it wouldn't take long (minutes not hours) to load it into html page and ajax it to php

Comment: Did you encode the array in javascript using JSON.stringify()?

Comment: @charlietfl my problem is not the time, but the issue is the $data in PHP is returning NULL, do I need to do some functions on it to convert into a PHP array

Comment: that isn't json currently is why php sees null when you try to decode it

Comment: @borna, i am getting the data from a export file, to do JSON.stringify() on it, i will have to take the second approach i think. load in jquery, do json.stringify and then pass the data to PHP using ajax

Comment: don't even need to stringify objects or arrays to send to $_POST using ajax

Comment: @charlietfl , can you suggest a way how i can convert the data into json or any other way in which i could add the data into my database

Comment: go for the ajax approach ... easier than me showing you how to edit those javscript statements to json. Likely faster in long run too if there's quite a bit of data

Comment: Okay, will do that, but if you can show me how to do it in the PHP file itself it will be super helpful

Comment: If use $.ajax and type post receive your data with $_POST...then iterate and do whatever inserts you need

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is not a valid JSON, you can use a regex to parse it, like this:

```
$file_content = file_get_contents('trial_data.js');
preg_match_all("/(\w+)\[\"([^\]]*)\"\]\s*\=\s*\{([^\}]*)\}/", $file_content, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    $data[$value][$matches[2][$key]] = json_decode('{'.$matches[3][$key].'}');
}
print_r($data);
//For example:
echo $data['users']['524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-16354d6351ae']->pictureName;
//Output: 66s2c.jpg
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/fW5gH

Comment: I have another problem, i also need to get the information for the required user from the top of the file it has the following format ||  index = {
  "me" : {
    "id" : "524bd089-2a7b-4a71-ba23-1635451ae",
    "firstName" : "a",
    "lastName" : "T",
    "pictureName" : "66s2c.jpg",
    "username" : "a-y"
  },
   {
    "user" : {
      "id" : "60c4a171-172f-4f66-9014-8b4cf3e476e6",
      "firstName" : "B",
      "lastName" : "I",
      "pictureName" : "",
      "username" : "bi"
    }
  } ]
} I need the id from the me field can you help me figure out the regex for the same.

Comment: Could you please add it to your question.

Comment: Hey did you check the change i made to the code, how do i get the id value from the me field in in index